# Semantic-UI dropdown onChange event

Tags: event-handling, onchange, semantic-ui

Can someone help and explain to me why this code works fine in JSFiddle, firing onChange event, and not in chrome or firefox ?

In the browsers, dropdown works fine, but when I change the option, the onChange event doesn't fire.

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ngchagas/nh1uys6p/38/)

```
<div class="ui form">
  <div class="fields">
    <div class="eight wide field">
      <label>Name</label>
      <div class="ui fluid search selection dropdown">
        <input type="hidden">
        <i class="dropdown icon"></i>
        <div class="default text">select name...</div>
        <div id="country" class="menu">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

window.onload = function() {
  fill_tst(); 
};

function fill_tst(){
        $.ajax({
            url: "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/comments/",
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function(data) {
                var options='';
                for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                    options += '<div class="item" data-value="' + data[i].id + '">' + data[i].name + '</div>';
                }
                $("#country").append(options);
            }
          });
    };

    $('.ui.selection.dropdown').dropdown('setting', 'onChange', function(value, text){
        alert('valor: ' + value + '\n' + 'text: ' + text);
    });
```